# Can Tornado return HTML directly from a string?

Tags: python, html, tornado

The common usage of tornado return html is like:

```
return render(req, 'msg.html')
```

But as my message is only one sentence, I don't want build an html file, instead I wanna return html language directly. I tired

```
return render(req, '<h3>Invalid username</h3>')
```

but failed.

Is it possible to do it in tornado, how?

Comment: Can `tornado.web` help? Take a look at [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730945/in-tornado-is-it-possible-to-return-a-http-error-code-without-the-default-templa). Not exact but similar. May help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible using [RequestHandler.write](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.write). Sample code:

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ...
        ...
        self.write('<h3>Invalid username</h3>')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can produce a response directly using [RequestHandler.write](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.write)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [RequestHandler.finish](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.finish) method like this

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    ...
    ...
    self.finish('<h3>Invalid username</h3>')
```

This way your request will be not only written (as with using ´´write´´ method) but also finished and sent to the client (as render automatically does)